# why i cant change fonts size on screen 480-800-hdpi and sometimes good fonts are bad in real screen?

Tags: android, fonts, sdk

First of all i want to apologise for my bad english ;p i have a broblem with fonts in android. I created directories:

-values-small-ldpi

### -values-small-mdpi

etc.
with dimens.xml
and there i wrote font size for each screen

i'm checking everything via AVD or genymotion

i have two problems:
1) i can't do anything with font size on screen 480-800-hdpi, whatever i write in dimens.xml nothing happens... why?

2) most of screens are ok but yesterday my friend run app on his phone (something like Nexus) with fillHD and there fonts were too big. I had checked it on AVD and Genymotion in every high resolution everything was fine... why?

i hope someone will help me...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the values for a 480-800-hdpi screen should be put inside normal-hdpi (or simply hdpi).
As for the problem with your friend phone if you used sp while defining font sizez the font size will change depending on the settings your friend has inside the accessibility settings under font size

Comment: WOW you are right thanks :) , 480-800-hdpi shoud by in normal screen but why? Google says that 480-800 id large screen and for example 480-800-mdpi I change in large screen...

Comment: and problem in my friend. I'm using sp becouse everyone says that i have to do with fonts. Should I use dp instad of sp???

Comment: ok there is table in http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and 480-800-hdpi is in normal screen, my bad ;p and where should i configure 720-1280-xhdpi??? and haw should i use those font units, sp or dp???

Comment: Well, you should use sp indeed but if you use sp you also have to take care of scaling the ui depending on the font size. If you use dp the font size will always stay the same. If my answer helped you please mark it as accepted

Comment: ok so can I check what kind of scalling user set? and how to handle this? if I use dp instead of sp than font always will be the same... in the other hand user cant change font sizes than... hmmm i don't know what to do...

Comment: That's really a design decision. If you want the user to be able to scale fonts you have to manage fonts of different sizes.